# Excel VBA: speed up macro which sets column width and view settings

Tags: excel, vba

My team and I have an excel file where I use columns A to L. We use this file to send out different budgets and therefore have multiple versions of the file. What happens is that people start to adjust the column widths and afterwards the print area no longer fits.

We want to ensure a standardized layout version at all times.

I have set up a VBA that ensures that the pre-selected column widths are implemented upon opening the file. If somebody changes the width, this will automatically be adjusted when somebody else opens the file again.

The code I have works fine however, one problem is that it takes to long to run 2min30sec. Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

'-----START TIMER-----
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeTaken As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    Application.StatusBar = False

On Error Resume Next

'For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
For Each ws In Worksheets ' Start of the VBA loop
    With ws
    ws.Activate 'this part ensures each seperate tab is activated and the below code is run through
    Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 0.94 'this line determines the column width
    Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 6.56 'this line determines the column width
    Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("F").ColxumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 6.11
    Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 10.11
    Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 13.56
    Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 6.56
    Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 6.56
    Wsh.Range("A1").Select 'this part ensure each worksheet view start position is A1
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview 'Set Activesheet to Page Break Preview Mode
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 114 'this line sets the permanent zoom % for all tabs
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    End With

Next ws
Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("resume").Range("A1"), True 'starting position upon opening the file
'Worksheets(1).Activate 'this line make sure view is at first tab

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

'------ END TIMER------
TimeTaken = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "Running time was " & TimeTaken & " (hours, minutes, seconds)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try using the `Workbook_Open` event?

Comment: its not about what file they open. one file, multiple users, and across time users changes the column widths for there own purpose

Comment: So it doesn't sounds like you tried the `Workbook_Open` event. Give the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) a read. This is what you want. There are also examples here on SO of how to use it.

Comment: I use workbook_open for other code, such as print area and size. but don't know how to add a predetermined column widths

Comment: Please see the [`Range.ColumnWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth) documentation.